# Regex that doesn't start with character or doesn't contain a substring

Tags: regex

I would like to create a regex that would match words which doesn't start with `$` character or doesn't contain sustrings `inherit`, `initial`.

Regex should match:

```
rgb(0,0,0)
#ffffff
green
```

and doesn't should match

```
$green
inherit
initial
```

Comment: Try: `^(?!(?:\$|inherit|initial)).+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with multiple negative lookahead conditions:

```
^(?!(?:\$|inherit|initial)).+
```

which matches the start position and then using negative lookahead conditions, negates the match using 3 sub-matches.

RegEx Demo: https://regex101.com/r/kDpdkC/1